# Arrange Lighning layout in LWC so that children occupy all the space

Tags: lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

[Standard layout component `<lightning-layout>` from Lightning Design Bundle in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example) provide several options to arrange children components:

using `horizontal-align="spread"` would spread children components horizontally which is the part of what I am looking for but it uses too much space in between, also, it has extra space on the top and bottom
[image]

using `Vertical Align (Stretch)` would spread children components both horizontally and vertically and it seems this supplies what I am looking for, however, I am not able to scroll to find the corresponding code and when I apply  or  it doesn't work for me as it looks in this example
[image]

How can I achieve children arrangement occupying all space horizontally?
How can I find the corresponding code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find the corresponding code?

To find the corresponding code one can use "Open in Playground button"
[image]
See this in action
[image]
Once we opened playground, we have to scroll to the corresponding code.

> How can I achieve children arrangement occupying all space
>   horizontally?

To stretch items horizontally it is enough just to set `flexibility:auto` to children component. Refer to [`lightning-layout-item` specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/specification) and to the [auto flexibility example here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/example)
[image]
[By removing `padding="around-small"` in this example, we could achieve full stretch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/huVMvzN7U/1/edit)

[image]